# with more then 10,000 records in jquery datatable cannot scroll to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Data Table plugin where  I select a lot of data from server side. I try to using scroll to  display these huge data (more than 500,000) [like this](http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/extensions/scroller/examples/server-side_processing.html), 
but when I scroll to the end of the bottom , It's will back to top. And I found it's cannot scroll more than 10000 records. It's will back to top soon.

my code as follow,

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "ordering": true,
     "searching": true,
     "order": [[1, 'desc']],//default
      "lengthMenu": [
        [50, 100, 1000],
        [50, 100, 1000]
      ],

    "ajax": {
       url: "process.php",
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
       start: "<?php echo $start; ?>",
       end: "<?php echo $end; ?>"
          }

       },

    "columns": [
        {
            "className":'details-control',
            "orderable":false,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "time"},
    { "data": "message","orderable": false}

    ],
    "dom": 'frtiS',
    "scrollY": 600,
    "scroller": {

         "loadingIndicator": true
    },
    "deferRender":    true

} );
```

Please help me do that, or suggest better solution.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch records on scroll event, means by default fetch only 100/200 records and then fetch on scroll event fire

Comment: @user6556472 why don't you implement pagination

Comment: because my data is more than 500000 records, so i have to using scroll , pagination cannot display more than 10000 records. when records less than 10000, it's can scroll to the end of bottom ,but when records more than 10000, it's cannot work

Comment: @user6556472 that's exactly *why* you should use pagination

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan, use pagination still can display the eleventh page when each page have 1000 records

Comment: If someone needs to load 500,000 records, I think there is a UX issue. Might be a better way of filtering the data since trying to located something in 500,000 things seems like a bad day for a user.

Comment: @user6556472 I think what folks are suggesting, is that you paginate the data, and only have 1 page loaded in the grid at a time.  So you would never actually have more then 10,000 records loaded in the grid at one time, and therefore scrolling to the bottom would work.  Obviously, searching, filtering, and sorting for a dataset that large will likely need to occur server side.

Comment: @ Mark At Ramp51 , I have tried to use pagination , but still cannot display the eleventh page when each page have 1000 records ,please  point me out the correct way to do it.